# React Native iOS Build - Directory not found for option

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

### Description

I'm doing the build process of my IOS app with the App Center. But it runs pod install and in the next step it uses .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace folder. It gives an error of directory not found.

I would like to know why the error is happening with the .xcodeproj file and not with the .xcworkspace folder and what is that error, that will help me to prevent that happens again with other projects.

### React Native version:

0.61.2

### Steps

1) The installation of pod dependencies works fine

```
==============================================================================
Task         : CocoaPods
Description  : Install CocoaPods dependencies for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects
Version      : 0.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/cocoapods
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod --version
1.7.5
[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories
....
[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `FastFeet.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 24 dependencies from the Podfile and 25 total pods installed.
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.
##[section]Finishing: Pod install
```

2) Xcode build step uses sgeo.xcodeproj instead sgeo.xcworkspace and uses. That's why it fails and would to know why.

```
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (not signed)
==============================================================================
Task         : Xcode
Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.
Version      : 4.130.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613730)
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 10.3
Build version 10G8
##[warning]Output directory for build output (binaries) ignored. Specifying an output directory is incompatible with the 'archive' action.
[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/ios/sgeo.xcodeproj -scheme sgeo clean archive -archivePath /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/output/build/archive/sgeo.xcarchive CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO

...

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sgeo-byybcvsvzaukpqcrnnthwhpvohyi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sgeo/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sgeo-byybcvsvzaukpqcrnnthwhpvohyi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sgeo/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-DevSupport'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sgeo-byybcvsvzaukpqcrnnthwhpvohyi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sgeo/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTActionSheet'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sgeo-byybcvsvzaukpqcrnnthwhpvohyi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sgeo/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sgeo-byybcvsvzaukpqcrnnthwhpvohyi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sgeo/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sgeo.build/Release-iphoneos/sgeo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/sgeo normal arm64
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (not signed)
```

#### Expected Results

App Center Build step needs to detect the .xcworkspace folder instead of .xcodeproj, and uses it to the pod install step.

#### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

https://ibb.co/jWWVjb2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... i found the reason of the error in the App Center Documentation.

If you configure the App Center automatically via the react-native link, you must open the project's `ios/{appname}.xcworkspace` file in Xcode. Like App Center dependencies, CocoaPods works only with xcworkspace and not xcodeproj, and the `ios /{appname}.xcodeproj` file will not have linked App Center CocoaPods dependencies.

All of this information is provided by the Application Center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native#42-build-and-run-your-application-from - xcode-or-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Actually, the iOS deployment target is defined in Project>Info>Deployment is 11 and also in PodFile its iOS 11. But in Targets>Build Settings>Basic>Deployment>iOS Deployment Target was set to 9.

I just changed to iOS 11 on all places.
It works.